# How to configure interface for FPGA using Red Hawk SDR

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to start using the Red Hawk SDR with a custom data acquisition board, but the documentation does not seem clear enough on exactly how to interface with custom FPGA based hardware. Is there any tutorial or explanation of how to get started with this. I have already read through this documentation https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch6.html#x8-1110006.